# Writing a method using getArray() in Java that returns an array of integers

Tags: java, arrays

I am in a a JAVA programming class online and I need some help with making an array.  I have asked some fellow class mates to no avail.  I need to make write a method using the getArray() method that will return an array of integers with the capacity of 500.

I do know how to write a JAVA statement that initializes an array of integers with a capacity of 500.  However, it nots helping me much. (i named the array "values")

int [] values = new int [500];

Please be timely if you answer this. I need to know how to do this before Wednesday 2/5/14 Thank You

Comment: Heres a big hint from the world of software (or even life) `try it and see`

Comment: do you mean toArray() from Collections?  Java has no built in getArray() method.  There is one in JDBC but I don't think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Well specifically I mean an array method for Android Studio that will allow me to return an array of integers at a set capacity.

Comment: the IDE you are using doesn't really clarify your question. sorry, I would help if I knew what you were looking for.

Comment: Okay.  What would help clarify my question.

Comment: Hey user 3109924.  I dont know what you mean the question I though was straight forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int[] getArray(){
 return new int[500];
}
```